# How to make old Android browser versions (on Android 2.3) render position:fixed correctly?

Tags: android, css, css-position

I've some problem, because it works on FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE 9/10/11, and on new Android version of mobile device, but on the old Android Browser (as supplied with android version 2.3) the position is relative to the top:0 of the DOC and not to the WINDOW.

CSS

```
.tooltip {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 110px auto;
}
```

The css above is used for a pop up tooltip which is rendered on the viewport in every browser other than the old Android Browser. In the old Android Browser it is at the top of the document instead of the window.

If I fix for android old version, I ruin it for the new mobile browsers and vice versa. How can I fix for all devices?

Comment: You can't. Android's own browser is notorious for its poor performance; it's even worse than IE7. What I do is detect that browser and inform the users that they should use Chrome or Firefox. Especially the first is very easy for them, because practically all Android tablets come with Chrome installed as well. If you would like to know how to detect that browser, let me know and I'll post the code. It's not a one-line script, but it can very well be done.

Comment: There might be a way after all: giving the `html` and `body` elements a padding and a margin of 0. Thereby, your are 'stretching' them to the canvas. Nonetheless, I would still advise you to ask droidDroid users to use Chrome. I have even seen newer droidDroids make rendering errors where older ones did do it correctly. So, you would have to check your site in every droidDroid version.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments below the question, a Javascript to detect Android's own browser (which will be called 'droidDroid'; the Android OS will be called 'Android'):

```
var uA = navigator.userAgent;
var pf = navigator.platform;
var browser = null;
var OS = null;
var screenType = null;

if ('ontouchstart' in window || window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) 
    screenType = 'touchScreen';
if (pf.indexOf("Linux") >= 0  &&  screenType == 'touchScreen')
    OS = 'Android';
if (OS == 'Android'  &&  uA.indexOf('Firefox') == -1  &&  uA.indexOf('Chrome') == -1  &&  uA.indexOf('iPad') == -1  &&  uA.indexOf('Opera') == -1) 
    browser = 'droidDroid';
    // On some Android devices, Chrome has 'iPad'(!) in stead of 'Chrome' in its uA.
if (browser == 'droidDroid') 
    alert('For this website, you should use Chrome or Firefox, due to the structurally poor performance of Android\'s own browser.');
```

.
If not fully self-explanatory, just let me know. Two issues though:

1. This script does not make a distinction between droidDroid versions. The reason is that also the latest droidDroid versions have serious problems, with a whole range of matters.
2. This script does not advise Opera, because that is on its way out rapidly (the makers have switched to the WebKit engine, including WebKit uA). If it ever was a proper mobile browser, and thus if it ever was used by mobile-device users.

Comment: I'd like a script which recognizes if the Android version is lower that version 3.0